# How to setup travis build to pull private gradle dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci, artifactory

I am new to travis and trying to pull in a jar from a private server.

I followed [this guide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en) and now have the jar hosted on the server which can be used in other projects by registering the repository in the `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://IPADDRESS:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_username}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
```

The credentials are placed in the `#HOME_DIR/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.

```
artifactory_username=YOUR_USERNAME
artifactory_password=YOUR_ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD
```

It is working on our machines but the build on travis fails as it doesn't have that `gradle.properties` file. What is the proper way to handle this i.e to setup travis to pull from that repo?

I guess I could define them as [environment variables in repository settings](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) but it looks like that would require modifying the build.gradle file to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your travis build script you can add -P options to the gradle commands. These will add the project properties for you.

```
gradle -PprojectProperty=projectValue build
```

The password is not very well protected when you add it to git though. To protect it use an encrypted environment variable. Follow [this guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypting-environment-variables) to encrypt the variables. Once the environment variable is available in the travis build script you can use it like this.

```
gradle -Partifactory_username=username -Partifactory_password=${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD} build
```

The great thing about this approach is developers can continue with their current configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to pass the properties to `gradle assemble` on the install block. Works well.